# iOS: UISplitViewController show/hide master view button doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am learning objective C. Now I am curios with UISplitViewController and show/hide master view button. I have seen a lot of tutorial but I do something wrong and I don't know what is it. My button doesn't hide master view. I absolutely broke my mind in two days. Now I built this sample project to ask your advice.
In my pattern I have: TabBarVC, SplitVC, TableViewVC and ViewVC. All controllers are my custom.
MyTabBarViewController is coming first. I has the tab with UISplitViewController.

MySplitViewController.m

```
#import "MySplitViewController.h"
#import "MyTabBarViewController.h"
#import "MyDetailViewController.h"

@interface MySplitViewController ()

@end

@implementation MySplitViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyTabBarViewController *masterVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTableVC"];
    MyDetailViewController *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myDetailVC"];

    NSArray *newViewControllersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterVC, detailVC, nil];

    self.viewControllers = newViewControllersArray;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


@end
```

MyTableViewController.m

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@interface MyTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

//configure the cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

MyDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyDetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *showHideMasterVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popover;

@end
```

MyDetailViewController.m

```
#import "MyDetailViewController.h"

@interface MyDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    //Grab a reference to the popover
    self.popover = pc;
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
 invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    //Nil out the pointer to the popover.
    _popover = nil;
}

@end
```

Here's my whole project with storyboard: [MyProject](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1338320/SplitVCTest.zip)

Sorry for a lot of code, but please help me or I get crazy. Thank you!
PS By the way is it possible to have show/hide master view button outside NavigationController, on some view for example?

And now I got that - (void)splitViewController(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController and - (void)splitViewController(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController is deprecated in iOS8.

So can somebody correct my project what I should do for solving my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to add `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;` in your MyDetailViewController `viewDidLoad`. This will show the show/hide MasterDetailViewController button.

And your `- (void)splitViewController(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController` and `- (void)splitViewController(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController` is deprecated in iOS8.

I had a similar problem, and for me, I solved it by simply creating my project with Master-Detail Application template. It comes with show/button and `- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController` as a default. If you are using a TabBarViewController as a rootViewController then you might want to set that as the rootViewController in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Hope this will help solve your problem.

**Edit:**

*PS By the way is it possible to have show/hide master view button outside NavigationController, on some view for example?*

First create a UIButton in your storyboard. Connect it to IBAction.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;
[self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem action];
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I didn't get your point how should I do this without using of deprecated methods?

Comment: You don't need the deprecated methods. Just add `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;`.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi Sansof, could you help me with two things of this new methods, please? 1. How to load UI with hidden masterVC by default? 2. How to hide masterVC after row tap? Thank you! Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: I already know just put self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden; Thanks! Sorry!